# How can I check whether an item of an Entity's child collection exists in another collection with LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, intersect

I hope that somebody caught the idea from the question, but I didn't know how to summarize it better.

The thing is I try to make a simple search in an application. I have Question and Tag entities, like these in StackOverflow - in a many-to-many relationship.

I pass an array of tag IDs to my filtering method. It should return all the Question entities that have this tags (with this IDs). I did it like this:

```
int[] tagIds = { 1, 2, 3};
var questions = myEntities.Questions
                    .ToList()
                    .Where(q => tagIds.Intersect(q.Tags.Select(t => t.Id).ToArray()).Any())
                    .ToList();
```

Everything worked fine, but now I added more filters and more methods use this filter, so I want to get a DbQuery object, instead of a List.

I tried removing the .ToList() expressions, to get the appropriate result:

```
int[] tagIds = { 1, 2, 3};
var questions = myEntities.Questions
                    .Where(q => tagIds.Intersect(q.Tags.Select(t => t.Id).ToArray()).Any());
```

Unfortunatelly, I get an exception, stating that LINQ does not recognize the .ToArray() method. Can anyone give me a better idea how to achieve this?

Comment: you dont need to use toArray there I think

Comment: Yes! Thank you, you are right. You may post this as an answer, so that I could mark it as best. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ToArray() method isnt even needed in

```
.Where(q => tagIds.Intersect(q.Tags.Select(t => t.Id).ToArray())
```

because Intersect just needs an IEnumerable that Select already returns and not necessarily an array.